# Unity Player Controller - how to make it so it doesn't go upside down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

This is my CamMouseLook script and I need it so when the player moves the mouse all the way up it doesnt turn upside down. I want him to be able to look up just not so much up that it turns the view upside down

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamMouseLook : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector2 mouseLook;
    Vector2 smoothV;
    public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float smoothing = 2.0f;

    GameObject character;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        character = this.transform.parent.gameObject;   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        var md = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

        md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
        smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
        smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);
        mouseLook += smoothV;

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
        character.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x, character.transform.up);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to lock the rotation in a specific axis. For example to limit in the Y and X axis so the player can only rotate from [-60,60] degrees you can use:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mouseSensitivity = 70.0f;
    public float clampAngle = 60.0f;

    private float rotY = 0.0f; // rotation around the up/y axis
    private float rotX = 0.0f; // rotation around the right/x axis

    void Start ()
    {
        Vector3 rot = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
        rotY = rot.y;
        rotX = rot.x;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float mouseY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        rotY += mouseX * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        rotX += mouseY * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, -clampAngle, clampAngle);

        Quaternion localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, 0.0f);
        transform.rotation = localRotation;
    }
}
```

Now you can adapt this script to limit the rotation in the angle and the range you need